# Using Different Connection Strings in Local Development

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, connection-string

I have an Umbraco project with multiple developers working on it, each developer has a different connection string for their local database. The process currently is that we change the connection string in the web config locally which works until the next `git push`/`gitpull` when it's overrided and we have to manually revert the connection string.

I've seen a plugin called SlowCheetah that allows local web config trasnforms but have had very mixed results with it so am ideally looking for something more robust.

How is this issue normally solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found what I think is a fairly simple workaround for this using the `configSource` attribute. We're now holding the connection strings in an external file `connections.txt` which is simply ignored in git and referenced in the web config file.

In the web config:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="connections.config"/>
```

And the text file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CONNECTIONNAME" connectionString="CONNECTIONSTRING" providerName="PROVIDERNAME" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [ConfigurationBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationbuilder), introduced in .NET Framework 4.7.1, to pre-process the config XML / section relevant to your configuration before it is used by other code. You could use environment variables such as Machine names or user names to modify the connection strings section or appSettings section.

I have a [blog post](https://dasmulli.blog/2018/01/21/use-appsettings-json-and-environment-overrides-in-classic-asp-net-apps/) out there which details implementing loading configuration from different json files based on an `ASPNET_Environment` environment variable but you can probably accomplish a more targeted change with less code.

Comment: Came here to say that the solution in your blog post is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Have a connectionstring like this:
`DefaultConnection": "Data Source=.\\;Initial Catalog=database;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"`
It uses window authentication to access db.